# How to use voice in Telegram VoIP?

Tags: telegram, voip, telegram-api

I have code that initializes a Telegram voice call (phone.ConfirmCall, key exchange).
Next, Telegram gives me 3 IP addresses in phone.PhoneCall.
In theory, what should I do next to, for example, play an audio file in a P2P call?

I attempted to establish UDP connections with those IP addresses, send random bytes packets, etc.